# Questions for having clause and where clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a very simple question. I am using Mysql bench, and i had a data which likes below:

```
dateordered_new        orderstatus  orders
2016-06-23 23:19:23     returned       8
2016-06-01 23:19:23     completed     12
2016-06-22 23:19:23     returned       9
2016-06-04 23:19:23     completed     27
...etc...
```

The question is simple, I want to show the amount of orders which has been returned in each month.

And here is my query:

```
select month(dateorderednew) as Month, sum(orders) as return_orders
from table_a
group by month
having orderstatus='returned;
```

Considering the difference between where clause and having clause, my syntax should be worked. However, the system told me that "Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'orderstatus' in 'having clause'" And it was wired.

However, when I modified my query like this:

```
select month(dateorderednew) as Month, sum(orders) as return_orders
from table_a
where orderstatus='returned
group by month;
```

And it worked.

So, it was really confusing. I think having clause should follow by the group by statement. But I cannot answer why this case happened?

Do you guys have any idea for this?

Answer (score 1):

In your situation, you should use a `where` clause:

```
select month(dateorderednew) as Month, sum(orders) as return_orders
from table_a
where orderstatus='returned'
group by month
```

Because you want to filter rows from the table *before* they are aggregated.

You only use `having` clause when you want to filter on an *aggregate* value, eg

```
select month(dateorderednew) as Month, sum(orders) as return_orders
from table_a
group by month
having sum(orders) > 10
```

However, mysql is flexible and allows you to use a `having` on a non-aggregate value.

Answer (score 1):

`HAVING` is used to filter out results of aggregations, like `MIN/MAX/AVERAGE`, while `WHERE` is used to filter on non-aggregate columns.

For example, you can do this:

```
select month(dateorderednew) as Month, sum(orders) as return_orders
from table_a
WHERE orderstatus='returned'
group by month
having sum(orders) < 100
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace the condition mentioned the **having clause with where clause**. Because `having clause filter the data on aggregated group` and `where clause filter the data on whole record set`.

Try the below SQL:

```
Select month(dateorderednew) as Month, sum(orders) as return_orders
from table_a
where orderstatus='returned
group by month;
```

Answer (score 0):

A 'WHERE' clause filters on individual row values...

`where colname > 0` 
 or

```
where colname = 'sometext'
```

A 'HAVING clause filters on a group or aggregate of a row and comes after the 'group by' statement if there is one...

```
group by colname
having count(*) > 0
```

or

```
group by colname   
having sum(colname) < 1
```